# How to apply view-side filtering in MVVM?

Tags: mvvm, view, telerik, viewmodel

I'm using Telerik RadGridView in my project (which essentially is a standart GridView).
This component has its own filtering functionality and I want to get advantage of it.

Filtering itself I am planning to do based on several combobox selected values. So if I got right idea of MVVM, I  need to bind the combos to some ViewModel's properties. But here's a problem of how to pass these selected values back to View's component? how to make it refresh filtering as selected value change?

upd: I use SimpleMVVM framework.

XAML of MainWindow:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
......
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MainPageViewModel}">

<StackPanel Height="auto">
    <telerik:RadMenu VerticalAlignment="Top">
    ......            
    </telerik:RadMenu>
    <my:Expander VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="auto" Width="auto"/>
    <my:CustomerView Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="auto" Width="auto"/>
</StackPanel>
```

XAML of expander:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
...... >


<Grid Margin="10,10,0,10" Width="684" Height="97" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >

    <telerik:RadExpander x:Name="radExpander" IsExpanded="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" telerik:AnimationManager.IsAnimationEnabled="True" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <telerik:RadComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="244,-2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="154" Height="26" 
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllLevels}" DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEventLevel}"/>
 .......

        </Grid>
    </telerik:RadExpander>
</Grid>
```

XAML of CustomerView:

```
       <telerik1:RadGridView Name="EventList" .... ItemsSource="{Binding SportEventsList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <telerik1:RadGridView.Columns>
 .....
        </telerik1:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik1:RadGridView>
```

Snippet of Viewmodel's code:

```
      private ObservableCollection<sportevent> _sportEventsList;
  public ObservableCollection<sportevent> SportEventsList
  {
      get { return _sportEventsList; }
      set
      {
          _sportEventsList = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged(vm => vm.SportEventsList);
      }
  }
```

Comment: How do you imagine a filtering? You want to use your own combos or built-it RadGridView's functionality? Just bind `Selecteditem` to `ViewModel`'s property to pass the selected value back to `View`

Comment: @AndreyGordeev The combos from which I get parameters of filtering have nothing to do with RadGRidView. They are separate controls bound to properties on ViewModel. Since I plan to make filtering in RGV programmatically, in the View, it needs to get actual property's values and update a filter.

Comment: Then do as I said - bind `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem` of your `ComboBox` to `ViewModel`'s properties

Comment: @AndreyGordeev Okay >> And I get properly updated Viewmodel's properties. And after that I need to reconstruct RadGridView's filter in View-code but the ViewModel knows nothing about the View. So I need somehow to pass newly selected parameters to View

Comment: Don't you use `RaisePropertyChanged` for that? Please, post your XAML and `ViewModel`'s code. Which MVVM Framework do you use?

Comment: @AndreyGordeev I'm a newbe in MVVM and WPF yet, till now I just bound VM's properties to BOUNDABLE properties of View, but when it came to some customization, I got stucked (

Answer (score 0):

Add the following properties to your VM:

```
    private ObservableCollection<yourType> allLevels;
    public ObservableCollection<yourType> AllLevels
    {
        get
        {
            return allLevels;
        }
        set
        {
            allLevels = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("AllLevels");
        }
    }

    private yourType selectedEventLevel;
    public yourTypeSelectedEventLevel
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedEventLevel;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedEventLevel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedEventLevel");
        }
    }
```

I assume `MainPageViewModel` inherits `SimpleViewModelBase`